# Knockout computed property outputs function body

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm new to knockout i'm trying to get the value of a computed property but all i get is the function body.
My ViewModel is

```
    var AuthorViewModel = function (data) {
    this.id        = ko.observable(data.id);
    this.firstName = ko.observable(data.firstName);
    this.lastName  = ko.observable(data.lastName);
    this.email     = ko.observable(data.email);
    this.phone     = ko.observable(data.phone)
    this.address   = ko.observable(data.address);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function () {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    },this);
};
```

But instead of getting the concatened string i get

```
    function observable() {
    if (arguments.length > 0) {
    // Write

    // Ignore writes if the value hasn't changed
    if ((!observable['equalityComparer']) || !observable['equalityComparer'](_latestValue, arguments[0])) {
    observable.valueWillMutate();
    _latestValue = arguments[0];
    if (DEBUG) observable._latestValue = _latestValue;
    observable.valueHasMutated();
    }
    return this; // Permits chained assignments
    }
    else {.....
```

Update sorry for not posting the view

```
<h1>Demo Application</h1>

<ul data-bind="foreach: authors">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="text: fullName()"></span>
        <a href="#" data-bind="click: edit">Edit</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<div>
    <button class="btn" data-bind="click: addAuthor">Add Author</button>
</div>
```

Any help would be appreciated

**Update 2 The AuthorsViewModel**

```
   var AddAuthorViewModel = function() {
        this.id = ko.observable();
        this.firstName = ko.observable();
        this.lastName = ko.observable();
        this.email = ko.observable();
        this.phone = ko.observable();
        this.address = ko.observable();
    };

    AddAuthorViewModel.prototype.template = "AddAuthor";

    AddAuthorViewModel.prototype.add = function () {
        this._requireModal();

        var newAuthor = {
            id        : this.id,
            firstName : this.firstName,
            lastName  : this.lastName,
            email     : this.email,
            phone     : this.phone,
            address   : this.address,
        };
        // Close the modal, passing the new author object as the result data.
        this.modal.close(newAuthor);
    };
```

The AppViewModel

`/`

```
 The root view model for the application
    var AppViewModel = function() {
        this.authors = ko.observableArray();
    };

    AppViewModel.prototype.addAuthor = function() {
        showModal({
            viewModel: new AddAuthorViewModel(),
            context: this // Set context so we don't need to bind the callback function
        }).then(this._addAuthorToAuthors);
    };

    AppViewModel.prototype._addAuthorToAuthors = function (newAuthorData) {
        this.authors.push(new AuthorViewModel(newAuthorData));
    };
```

I'm actually using the tutorial from http://aboutcode.net/2012/11/15/twitter-bootstrap-modals-and-knockoutjs.html with just a few modifcations

Comment: How do you try to get the value?

Comment: But i get the same output if i use console log just before return.

Comment: Can you also post how do you fill in the `authors` array? Can't be that your `data.firstName` and `data.lastName` already an ko.observable? Because only in that case can your code produce your output...

Comment: I thinks you have a point, i think i've noticed the same think early, but unfortunetly i'm also new to javascript, but what i don't get is why do the other properties work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in the `newAuthor` creation part:

```
var newAuthor = {
    id        : this.id,
    firstName : this.firstName,
    lastName  : this.lastName,
    email     : this.email,
    phone     : this.phone,
    address   : this.address,
 };
```

Because with this code you are creating an object which references the observables themselves not their values.

So at the end in your `AuthorViewModel` the `data` object will have have observable properties which you wrap again into a new set of observable properties...

So you need to unwrap your observables when you are creating the `newAuthor` :

```
var newAuthor = {
    id        : this.id(),
    firstName : this.firstName(),
    lastName  : this.lastName(),
    email     : this.email(),
    phone     : this.phone(),
    address   : this.address(),
};
```